# How to effectively set approved, non approved and drafts for a Rails model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model in my app called `photos`. Any user can upload photos. When uploaded at first, I store them in a temporary field names `tempfile`. Then the admin can review them and approve them. If approved the `approved` field will be true and the photo will be uploaded the s3. The photo will be saved in the `file` field and the `tempfile` will be removed. The `submitted` field in the database will be set to true. If the upload fail, it will be marked in the database. If the photo is rejected, the user can resubmit them.

- So, in the normal view i need to show `approved` and non `failed uploads`
- If a user edit a photo it should be `unapproved` and `submit` until the admin approve them
- In the resubmit menu I have to show `unapproved`, `unsubmitted` photos
- If user resubmit, the submit field will be set to true

By the looks of it I have to use a lot of database fields and it gets complex. Is there a way to handle this better? A way to save draft and save unapproved separately? How to do this effectively?

**Update : Thanks to @Alex I found out that I can do it with states machines. There's AASM, Workflow and statesman. What might be the best for this scenario?**

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered single table inheritance?  It would allow you to split this out into multiple classes.

Comment: Thanks :-) I found that I can use states machines for this. Any idea of a good gem for this situation?